# MVC Sitemap renders empty when the current action is not in the Mvc.sitemap file

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemapprovider

Is it possible to force the sitemap control to render the menu when the current action is not listed in the MVC.sitemap file?

I have a simple top nav.  When the current action is in the sitemap, the call to `.Menu()` will render the correct `<ul><li>..` data.  However, if I got to a page that is *not* in the sitemap such as /Home/Login, then it will not render any html at all (not even a comment, just empty space).  This isn't an `[authorize]` issue; the menu is fine when i'm in '/Home/Index'.

It seems like it should render what was requested, but just not set the `IsCurrentNode` and `IsNodeInPath` properties.  Here is the call I am making

```
<div id="main-nav">
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(0, true, true, 1)
</div>
```

The Mvc.sitemap file:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Form New Human" controller="Person" action="Create"/>
    <!-- there is no mvcSiteMapNode for "Home" "Login" -->
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way around it.  It apparently isn't a built in extension method, or at least I couldn't find one.  You could call `Html.MvcSitemap().Menu(Html.MvcSiteMap.Provider.RootNode,...)` but I didn't want to instantiate the helper twice.

```
<div id="main-nav">
@{
    var sm = Html.MvcSiteMap();
    @sm.Menu(sm.Provider.RootNode, true, true, 2);  // 2 levels (home, plus main nav)
}
</div>
```

Looking around in the disassembly seems to show that it works a little like this:

- You *really* need a starting node
- If you don't give it one, it tries to find one based on the current node

  - plus restrictions (forward searching, depth restrictions, etc)
  - if you want nodes from level 1, you have to know what level you are on
- Since that returns null, starting node is null, which means the helper writes an empty string

There may be a combination of tricks, or an overload or two, which can be finagled into doing this, but I can't find it right now.  This works for my needs (simple top menu).  There has to be a simpler way to do this, something with wild cards, or route based, with a closest match thing going on.  I figured menus were a fairly standard part of a web app, and this would be covered :)